# Spring+Spring security+tiles. How to set form-login with tiles page definition?

Tags: security, spring, authentication, mapping, tiles

I have spring_tiles web application and now trying to add spring security to it:

That is a peace of my TilesConfig.xml:

```
 <definition name="loginPage" extends="commonPage">
  <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/jsp/login_body.jsp" />
 </definition>
```

Here comes my spring mapping part:

```
<bean id="urlMapping"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="interceptors">
   <list>
    <ref bean="openSessionInViewInterceptor" />
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="mappings">
   <props>
    <prop key="/main.htm">mainController</prop>
    <prop key="/category.htm">viewCategoryController</prop>
    <prop key="/good.htm">goodController</prop>
    <prop key="/registration.htm">registrationController</prop>
    <prop key="/login.htm">?</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

And here is a part from applicationContext-security.xml:

```
 <http auto-config='true'>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" filters="none"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/login.htm*" filters="none"/>
  <form-login login-page="/login.htm" />
 </http>
```

But I wonder how should I set up my tiles page definition to the mapping. In all other pages I used controllers but I suppose I should not use any loginController in that case because Spring Security do that instead.

So, here is my question: how to map tiles loginPage to /login.htm within spring security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do it. In the spring config I've added this:

```
<bean id="loginController"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
    <property name="viewName" value="loginPage" />
</bean>
```

And in the mapping accordingly add that:

```
<prop key="/login.htm">loginController</prop>
```

Tiles and security configurations remained the same.

Answer (score 2):

By default, there is nothing specific in the configuration for spring security with tiles.

If the name of your login page tile is `loginPage`, I guess you should have something similar to the following in your `applicationContext-security.xml`

```
<intercept-url pattern="/loginPage" filters="none"/>
<form-login login-page="/loginPage" />
```

If you are using spring security, the login page would have a POST url, which goes to `/j_spring_security_check` (by default).  This is the equivalent of the `loginController`.

Comment: I've tried that - and it just redirects to http://localhost:8080/myapp/loginPage instead of using tiles view. But I found a way to realise that - look at the answers... I just have a poor knowledge about Spring - that was a problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to have the following controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Locale locale, Model model) {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/error", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginWithError(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("error", true);
        return "login";
    }
}
```

In security-context.xml, configure form-login as follows:

```
<form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login/error" />
```

In views.xml declare the login view:

```
<definition name="login" extends="template">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Nuevo Usuario"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/login.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

finally, in login.jsp, to show the error in case there is one, use the following code:

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <font color="red"> Error al ingresar. <br /> Motivo :
        ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
    </font>
</c:if>
```